# How to update a python string variable into a JSON file - ERROR: TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Tags: python, json

```
    Var = "Jonathan"
    new_data = {"premium": + Var}
    json_object['classes'][states].update(new_data)
```

This was the code I used, the error I got was this: TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

How can I work around this? In the actual code the string is not Jonathan, it is something that is created by the code.

Comment: new_data = {"premium": + Var} is wrong ... colon should be inside double quote..
new_data = {"premium : "+ Var}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
Var = "Jonathan"
new_data = {"premium": Var}
```

just remove `+` sign

Comment: You are a legend mate, thank you sm i had been stuck on this for the past hour!!!

Comment: also if you find this is as a nice answer you can ✔️ so that other fellow stack members know if he find same doubt as yours.!!